# JQuery is it possible to show message when ul element is empty and hide on items' add?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

The question is in the title. I have an ul element with no list items, and I need to show a message (it can be a li element) where the user can see that the list is empty. Once an item is added to the ul, the message should hide or remove.

The list can be updated dynamically, so if someone removes all the li elements contained on the ul, it should display the message again.

I have this, but only displays the message when the page loads:

```
if( !$("#minuta_minuta_participante_list_ul").has("li").length ) {
  $("#minuta_minuta_participante_list_ul").html("Sorry, this is empty");
}
```

Sorry if the question is to poor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the code/your attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with CSS empty and before, no need for JavaScript to add/remove the message.

```css
ul:empty:before {
  content: "I am empty"
}
```

```html
<h3>Empty</h3>
<ul></ul>

<h3>Not Empty</h3>
<ul><li>li</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use jquery you have to have know how many elements are in the list work off that. @epascarello answer is much cleaner and nicer.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  if ($('#list li').length == 0) {
    $('#list').append('<div id="mssg">Empty List</div>');
  }
  $('#add').on('click', function() {
    if (count == 0) {
      $('#mssg').remove();
    }
    $('#list').append('<li id="element-' + count + '">List Element ' + count + '</li>');
    count++;
  });
  $('#remove').on('click', function() {
    if (count > 0) {
      $('#element-' + (count - 1)).remove();
      count--;
    }
    if (count == 0 && $('#mssg').length == 0) {
      $('#list').append('<div id="mssg">Empty List</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='list'>

</ul>
<input type='button' value='Add' id='add' />
<input type='button' value='Remove' id='remove' />
```

Comment: Appending a div to a ul?

Comment: just as a message, it can also be a `li`